# In java getting different value for TimeZone.getDefault().getID() on different system

Tags: java, time, timezone

I am getting different value for TimeZone.getDefault().getID() on different systems.
For example, in case of Indian standard time,
On one of the system we are getting  "GMT+5:30":
while on another we are getting "Asia/Calcutta".
We are expected to get "Asia/calcutta" strings on all machines.

Why is there an inconsistency for such behavior?

Is there any way to get consistent behavior across different systems windows/MAC?

What is the best way to get client time zone programmatically  using Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the two machines are configured differently - it's as simple as that. For example, if your first system is Windows you *may* have unticked the box saying "Automatically adjust for Daylight Saving Time".

If you know you need Asia/Calcutta for all systems, then use that explicitly. I try to avoid using the default time zone wherever possible, to be honest. Even when I do use it, I try to use it *explicitly* so that it's obvious from the code that I'm *trying* to use the system time zone, rather than it just being accidental.

Comment: Thanks Jon, It was the same issue. (checking/ unchecking the "Automatically adjust for Daylight Saving Time" ). 
However, how can I expect someone using using my application to always select/deselect the checkbox.

Comment: @DeepakChaudhry: Well if they've unchecked the checkbox, perhaps they don't *want* to observe daylight saving time. At some point, you probably need to trust the user's choice. As far as anything is concerned, that *is* the user's time zone. Now you can always provide troubleshooting information in the documentation, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same problem on Linux and can't find an answer:

- Two linux machines set to `UTC`
- one JVM reporting incorrect timezone (ex `CET`)
- the other reporting correctly `UTC`

The problem could be:

- The faulty machine has this symlink: `/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris`
- `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris` contains `UTC` information

The cause for this could have been a simple `cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime` replacing the contents of `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris` instead of overwriting `/etc/localtime` which was a symlink instead of a file!